# Read list of xml sitemaps in Excel

Tags: excel, xml

In Excel table I have a column with urls to xml-sitemaps. What is the way to read the content of xml-sitemaps and write it into an Excel table (another tab or document)?

Input (Tab 1):

```
Column A
https://www.example.com/sitemap-01.xml
https://www.example.com/sitemap-02.xml
```

Expected output (Tab 2)

```
Column A;Column B
https://www.example.com/sitemap-01.xml;https://www.example.com/folder-01/page-x1.html
https://www.example.com/sitemap-01.xml;https://www.example.com/folder-01/page-x2.html
https://www.example.com/sitemap-02.xml;https://www.example.com/folder-02/page-y1.html
https://www.example.com/sitemap-02.xml;https://www.example.com/folder-02/page-y2.html
```